# How are $\epsilon$-nets (as in centers of $\epsilon$-ball covers) related to nets (as in topology)?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, nets

Here are two definitions that I have encountered:

The first, corresponding to [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delone_set), is the following.

> *Definition.*$\ $ Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}^{>0}$. An **$\epsilon$-net** for $X$ is a subset $S\subseteq X$ of points such that the collection of $\epsilon$-balls centered at those points forms a cover for X. i.e.,
> $$S\subseteq X \ \text{ is an }\epsilon\text{-net}\ \ \iff\ \ \bigcup_{x\in S}B_X(x,\epsilon)=X\ \ .$$ or equivalently
> $$S\subseteq X \ \text{ is an }\epsilon\text{-net}\ \ \iff\ \ \forall x\in X,\ \ \operatorname{dist}(x,S)<\epsilon \ .$$

The second, corresponding to [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)), is the following.

> *Definition.*$\ $Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space. Let $(P,\preccurlyeq)$ be a partially ordered set with the additional property that $\forall a,b\in X,\ \ \exists c\in X\ :\ a\preccurlyeq c\ \land\ b\preccurlyeq c\ $. $\,$A **net** $x$ is a function $x\colon P\to X$ and is also denoted as $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha\in P}$.

How are these two concepts related precisely? Since all metric spaces are topological spaces, the names would clash unless every $\epsilon$-net is a net.

Is it true that every $\epsilon$-net is a net? Or is the similarity in the names a mere unfortunate coincidence? To me, it looks like the two definitions are not related in any way.

Comment: You should include what your concerns are & what your thoughts on the concerns are , with a little more Detail

Comment: Okay, I'll edit the last part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No relation.
Words from English (and other languages) are frequently taken for technical use in mathematics, and sometimes (as here) in two (or more) unrelated ways.